# What is window["foo"]=function() {alert("foo");}

Tags: javascript, vue.js

reading the code I found out code like this

```
window["foo"]=
   function() {
      alert("foo");
   }
```

And if I call the function for example on `onclick("foo()")` I will get "foo"
So what is `window["foo"]` ?

Comment: It's...the `foo` property on `window`. [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406)

Comment: Basically it is creating property named "foo" under window object (that is always present),  and assigns function to this property. Same will be window.foo = function...

Comment: `window` is an object. `window["foo"]` is equivalent to `window.foo`

Comment: side note.... don't do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

foo is function declared as a prop in the window object which is the top level scope . which means your variable is accessed globaly from any place in you code , and its accessible like this :

```js
window["foo"]=
   function() {
      alert("foo");
   }


window["foo"]();
window.foo();
foo(); // this is your attempt on onclick
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Foo Word:](https://searchapparchitecture.techtarget.com/definition/foo-in-software-programming)

> Foo (pronounced FOO) is a term used by programmers as a placeholder
> for a value that can change, depending on conditions or on information
> passed to the program.

So, "Foo" is just a popular word among programmers like "Hello World" for the first program to learn code.

### The explanation for your code:

Your code creates a string property under the window object called "Foo" and assigns a function to this property which is the alert function so when JavaScript listens to a property called Foo (e.g the `onclick` function), it will call the alert function which you will see alert called "Foo".

### An example for JavaScript Objects & Properties:

```js
// JavaScript Object & Properties
// there are two different ways to access an object property
// you can use .property or ["property"].


var person = {
  firstname:"John",
  lastname:"Doe",
  age:50,
  eyecolor:"blue"
};

console.log(person["firstname"] + " is " + person["age"] + " years old.");
```

###### [Documentation for Javascript Objects & Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)